# Local host redirecting too many times

Tags: xampp, localhost

I Keep getting this when ever I want to run localhost

This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.
Try deleting your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I tried deleting third party cookies. What can I do solve this issue. I download snipe-it database but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: What do you mean "run localhost"? How are you running it? If there are too many redirects, I'm imagining that your `view` is faulty with permissions or whatnot, but without this info/info on how you run your code, your answer cannot be solved logically as it is just suggestions, which is not a good question for SO, for that -1

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, fixed it by changing APP_URL in the `.env` file (xampp>htdocs>snipe-it).

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Comment: This worked, thank you